# How to programmatically add videos to YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have a list of several YouTube URLs that I would like to add programmatically to a YouTube playlist (in my channel).  (Actually, I have several target playlists in mind, each getting a subset of the URLs in my list.)

Is there a way I can add these programmatically (e.g. with Python or Perl, etc.)?

p.s., (I <strike>imagine</strike> realize that there's a way to do this using the YouTube API, but my (very limited) understanding of this approach is that it would require me to create and register (with Google) a web app, and it would be this web app that would make API calls.  If this picture is correct, it looks like a lot of hassle for what I want to do.)

Edit: By way of clarification:

1. I *am* familiar with the info given [Adding a video to a playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Adding_a_video_to_a_playlist), but, as I explained, I am hoping to find some other
   way to do this.
2. I have no problem with registering *myself* to get a developer key, nor I have any problem with including a developer key with every request; but, in principle, including a developer key in one's requests does not require a webapp (a simple script, or even a command-line one-liner, is perfectly adequate, technically speaking, to this task); therefore, the webapp business seems to me an extraneous artifact of Google's registration procedure, one that greatly complicates what would otherwise be a very simple programming task.

Comment: You *can* achieve all these from command line. You don't have to have a webapp running.

Comment: I'm leaving a solution for those seeking *something* to solve this issue. YT has a "collaborative" playlist feature. We can let different users add items to our playlist.

Answer (score 3):

Youtube's API documentation has all the answers. Check the "[Adding video to playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Adding_a_video_to_a_playlist)" section. Here is a sample request for the same action -

```
POST /feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <id>VIDEO_ID</id>
  <yt:position>1</yt:position>
</entry>
```

P.S. -

> it looks like a lot of hassle for what I want to do

Using API is the only way to do it programmatically. And to use Google's API, you *have to* register a developer key to get the access token. You can use python/perl libraries to decrease the headache a bit, but you have to do them.

Comment: What's `yt:position`?